# How to Autowire an interface or abstract class without implementation in Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I need to Autowire an interface without an implementation, somehow like the 
@Repository tag functionality.

```
@QueryRepository
public interface EddressBookDao {

    @ReportQuery
    public List<EddressBookDto> loadEddresses(@EqFilter("id") Long id);

}

@Autowired
private EddressBookDao eddressBookDao;

Result result = eddressBookDao.loadEddresses(1L);
```

I'm thinking of somehow detecting my `@QueryRepository` Annotation during ClassPathScan and injecting a Proxy of `EddressBookDao` object on `eddressBookDao` Autowire.

Right now I am achieving this functionality in a cumbersome way using the following:

```
@Autowired
public ReportQueryInvocationHandler reportQuery;

private EddressBookDao eddressBookDao;

public EddressBookDao eddressBook(){
    if (eddressBookDao == null) eddressBookDao = reportQuery.handle(EddressBookDao.class);
    return eddressBookDao;
}
```

**Here is my Handler creating the Proxy:**

```
@Component
public class ReportQueryInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {
public <T> T handle(Class<T> clazz){
    return (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance(clazz.getClassLoader(), new Class[] { clazz }, this);
}

public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {

    Type returnType = method.getReturnType();

    Annotation[][] annotations = method.getParameterAnnotations();
    Report report = dao.createReport();

    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        Object argument = args[i];
        Annotation[] annotationList = annotations[i];
        if (annotationList.length == 0) continue;

        for (Annotation annotation : annotationList) {
            Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType = annotation.annotationType();
            String path = null;

            if (annotationType.equals(EqFilter.class)) {
                path = ((EqFilter) annotation).value();
                report.equalsFilter(path, argument);
                break;
            } 
        }
    } 
    return report.list((Class<?>) returnType);
}
```

**And here is how I'm calling my it:**

```
List<EddressBookDto> addressed = dao.eddressBook().loadEddresses(8305L);
```

**All I want is to avoid writing this code**

```
private EddressBookDao eddressBookDao;
public EddressBookDao eddressBook(){
    if (eddressBookDao == null) eddressBookDao = reportQuery.handle(EddressBookDao.class);
    return eddressBookDao;
}
```

**And write this instead:**

```
@Autowired
private EddressBookDao eddressBookDao;
```

Comment: Basically I have my own implementation of Hibernate, I dynamically build my own Criteria based on The ReturnType EddressBookDto and the Filter in the Param. I figured I should use same logic as @Repository and intercept method with AOP to create the Query and return the result.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data doesn't autowire interfaces although it might look this way. It registers factories which produce proxies implementing the interface.

To do something similar you have to implement the `FactoryBean` interface.
See [the JavaDoc for details](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html). There are also [tutorials available](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-factorybean).

Comment: Thanks for providing the link, but I think that my scenario is more complicated than the FactoryBean in the link provided. I have to somehow create my own interface annotation and have the ClassPathScanner to Pick it up...

Comment: Take a look at the `@EnableJpaRepository` annotation and the annotations it has itself.

Comment: Please check my updated code, I'm able to create a Proxy for the Interface, now I just need to create it using ClassPathScanning and Autowire it...